# Using regular expression for element which has changing numbers in between xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium, numbers, webdriver

In my application I have mails in the inbox and every mail has a different ID.
Im not able to click on the first mail as the mail id keeps on changing everytime.

The xpath is as follows:

```
//*[@id='r1295']/td[4]/a/font
```

In the above xpath the numbers after 'r...' keep on changing.

How to handle such changes.

Answer (score 3):

Try xpath function:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'r')]/td[4]/a/font
```